# How can i install ARR on azure VM via PowerShell?

Tags: iis, powershell, azure

I have deployed my project to Azure Cloud Service but additionally i must install Application Request Routing (ARR).

peace of .ps1 PowerShell command:

```
if( Get-Service was ) {
        Write-Host "Stopping IIS and WAS..."
        Stop-Service was -Force
    }


    $filepath="%temp%\arr.msi"
    $process = (Start-Process -FilePath msiexec -ArgumentList /i, $filepath, /qn -Wait).ExitCode

    Write-Host $process
    if( Get-Service was ) {
        Start-Service was,w3svc -Verbose
    }
```

output:

Downloading MSI packages...
Downloading MSI package: D:\Users\BUTTER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\arr.msi
Downloaded...
Done. Performing installation...
Stopping IIS and WAS...
1619
Done
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Start-Service" on Target "World Wide Web Publishing Service (w3svc)".
VERBOSE: Performing operation "Start-Service" on Target "Windows Process Activation Service (was)".

there is no error but it doesn't install ARR. can anyone help?

Comment: Any particular reason to use Powershell? [This blog for example](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/tag/azure-arr/) seems to have another way of doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't find a good way of doing this directly through PowerShell. If you don't mind using Chocolatey you can do it all from the Web Platform Installer Command Line (WebPICMD), example:

```
#Download and install Chocolatey and through Chocolatey install WebPICMD
iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString("https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1"))
cinst webpicommandline

#Install Url Rewrite and ARR
$webPiProducts = @('UrlRewrite2', 'ARRv3_0') 
WebPICMD /Install /Products:"$($webPiProducts -join ',')" /AcceptEULA
```

More info about WebPICMD here: http://www.iis.net/learn/install/web-platform-installer/web-platform-installer-v4-command-line-webpicmdexe-rtw-release

Inspiration for Chocolatey came from this blog post: http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/script-out-everything-initialize-your-windows-azure-vm-for-your-web-server-with-iis-web-deploy-and-other-stuff

Comment: You can also use `choco install webpicmd` if chocolatey is installed.

Comment: `cinst` is alias for `choco install`

Comment: This suddenly stopped working and says that there is a signature verification failure.  Any thoughts on this?